# Cucumber-JVM Maven Integration issue

Tags: testing, maven-3, cucumber-jvm

I was able to run Cucumber-JVM tests using  @RunWith & @CucumberOptions tags.But I am unable to execute  the tests using Maven. Can somebody point me in the right direction ?

I am trying to use maven sure fire plugin, after scouring the internet.I do think, I am making a mistake, which I dont't know abt.

Comment: Can you post how your jUnit test classes are annotated? Also, where are your feature files and jUnit test located?

Comment: The way I have created the test cases are: using the page object model for corresponding user actions and then mapped the action to statements including the assertions.So, I dont have the Junit testcases in the conventionally speaking. the Project Structure :

Comment: @CargoCult The Project Structure :  src -> test. | test -> config | test ->features | test -> steps. The RunCukeTests is in the steps package.  Does this help ?

Comment: Post the code of how you use RunWith & CucumberOptions

Comment: `package steps;


import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@CucumberOptions(format = {"pretty"}, features = {"."}, monochrome = true)
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCukeTests {
}
`

Comment: Can you show what did you try to run with Maven? That is, what arguments did you pass, how did you call etc.

Comment: Hi, I was finally able to solve the issue. The gist is @ https://gist.github.com/jags14385/451f8a81d0847a426f7a .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory structure is :

```
 src\test\ 
   --config\
   --resources\ (has the .feature files)
   --steps\  (classes for the steps)
```

===================maven POM file=======================

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Project</groupId>
<artifactId>Project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <cucumber.options>--format pretty</cucumber.options>
    <testsrc>src/test/</testsrc>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- External Dependency -->
        <groupId>ojdbc6</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>E:\work\test\Project\libs\ojdbc6dms.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- External Dependency -->
        <groupId>sqljdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>E:\work\test\Project\libs\sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${testsrc}</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/RunCukeTests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: why do you use `<parallel>classes</parallel>` together with `<threadCount>1</threadCount>`? It is to execute in parallel with one thread running which is the sam as sequential execution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Maven Compiler plugin as well.